# Sugar CRM in Joomla! installation folder, any possible issues?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7, sugarcrm

I'm interested to know if, by any chance, having a Sugar CRM installation inside a folder which is located in the same folder as Joomla! installation could/will cause future problems.

Folder structure:

```
C:\JoomlaFolder <- Joomla! installation folder
  \administrator
  \cache
  \cli
  \components
  \...many other folders and sub-folders specific to Joomla!
  \SugarCRMFolder <- here's where my Sugar CRM installation is located!
    \..many folders and sub-folders specific to Sugar CRM
```

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem but try it in a test environement before

Comment: @KevinPFEFER thank you, I'm already testing, but haven't found any issue yet, I thought I would ask before I get into any last minute trouble... there's always something! ((:

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Sugar CRM is? If it is not related to Joomla, it will make not any troubles for you.

Just go to `site.com` to access Joomla, and `site.com/administrator` to administering your site, as well as visiting Sugar CRM by `site.com/SugarCRMFolder` and `site.com/SugarCRMFolder/admin` as admin area

Comment: +1 thank you, I thought so also, but I'm thinking that maybe there's something that I'm missing and I don't want to risk it...

Comment: NO, be sure that everything's OK! ;)